# Numerical solution of pendulum equation

Tags: ode

Given a system of equations:

\begin{align}
&f''(x) = -a \cdot \sin(f(x))\\
&f(0) = b\\
&f'(0) = c
\end{align}

$a, b, c, dt, N$ are arbitrary parameters.

How to get a values of $f(0), f(dt), f(2dt) ... f(N)$. I am stuck with the non-linearity of the right part of the first equation.

I will be very glad, if someone will show me an implementation of an algorithm calculating this.

Comment: `I am stuck with the non-linearity of the right part of the first equation.` Does that comment mean that you are able to numerically solve the system for the linear case?

Comment: Yes, i can build a system of linear equations for each $f_i$ and build a matrix, which can be solved via Gaussian method.

Comment: It's better to be consistent in using x or t for the independent variable.

Comment: Since this is an initial-value problem, you can solve it numerically using the Euler method, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the functions $y_1 := f$, $y_2 := f'$, $\pmb{y} := (y_1,y_2)^{\top}$, we obtain an initial-value problem with an autonomous first-order system:
$$
\pmb{y}' = \left( \begin{array}{c}
y_2\\
-a \sin(y_1)
\end{array}
\right) =: \pmb{f}(\pmb{y}), \quad \pmb{y}(0) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
b\\
c
\end{array}
\right) =: \pmb{y}_0.
$$
We now choose the Euler method for the numerical solution:
$$
\pmb{y}_i = \pmb{y}_{i-1} + h \pmb{f}(\pmb{y}_{i-1}),
$$
$i = 1, 2, \dots$. This yields approximations $\pmb{y}_i \simeq \pmb{y}(x_i)$ at the positions $x_i = ih$.

Comment: Euler is of course just one simple possibility. For the conservation of energy it might be advantageous to use a symplectic method such as Verlet integration.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I know that Euler's method is not accuarate enough. Is there a way with better accuracy?

Comment: You could use a higher-order Runge-Kutta method instead of Euler, and/or reduce the step size $h$.

Comment: Higher order (explicit) RK does not imply a smaller step size. A-Stability has to be taken into account